# NetSuite SOAP API (SuiteTalk) to dump General Ledger

Tags: java, soap, netsuite

Can anyone give me advice on how to read the general ledger using `SuiteTalk`, the `SOAP` API from `NetSuite`?

For example, if you look at an account or a transaction on the `NetSuite` UI, there is an option to select "`GL Impact`". This produces a list of relevant general ledger entries.

However, I couldn't figure out a way to get the same list using `SuiteTalk`. One initially promising `SOAP` operation I tried calling was `getPostingTransactionSummary()`, but that is just a summary and lacks detail such as transaction dates. Another way is to call `search()` passing a `TransactionSearchBasic` object. That returns too many types of transaction and I'm not sure which of those actually have an impact on the general ledger.

I'm using `Java` and `Axis` toolkit for the `SOAP` operations, but examples in any language whatsoever (or raw `SOAP` `XML`) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are on the right track with your transaction search.
You are looking for posting is true and where the line has an account. 
However I'd set this up in the saved search editor at least until you've figured out how you are going to filter to manageable numbers of lines. Then use TransactionSearchAdvanced with savedSearchId to pull that info via SuiteTalk

Comment: Thanks bknights. I'm working with the "test drive" account and I have got a list that looks similar to the general ledger report on the UI, but there are several worrying discrepancies. Some transactions for some accounts appear in one but not the other and vice versa. Also, I'm confused about how an account is associated with a transaction. E.g. the General Ledger report for a/c 1090 - Undeposited Funds lists a CashSale record (internal ID 33) and I can get this if I do a joined search, but looking at the CashSale, the account is neither in the Account field nor in any sublist. Where is it?

Comment: You cannot filter out the main line. In addition to the other filters you use you might want to use a filter expression or formula field. Try  `case when {creditamount} is not null then 1 when {debitamount} is not null then 1 else 0 end`   in a formula numeric field with critera equalto 1.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to search GL transaction with below code, this could help you.

```
public void GetTransactionData()
{
    DataTable dtData = new DataTable();
    string errorMsg = "";
    LoginToService(ref errorMsg);

    TransactionSearch objTransSearch = new TransactionSearch();
    TransactionSearchBasic objTransSearchBasic = new TransactionSearchBasic();
    SearchEnumMultiSelectField semsf = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField();

    semsf.@operator = SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf;
    semsf.operatorSpecified = true;
    semsf.searchValue = new string[] { "Journal" };
    objTransSearchBasic.type = semsf;


    objTransSearchBasic.postingPeriod = new RecordRef() { internalId = "43" };

    objTransSearch.basic = objTransSearchBasic;


    //Set Search Preferences
    SearchPreferences _searchPreferences = new SearchPreferences();
    Preferences _prefs = new Preferences();
    _serviceInstance.preferences = _prefs;
    _serviceInstance.searchPreferences = _searchPreferences;
    _searchPreferences.pageSize = 1000;
    _searchPreferences.pageSizeSpecified = true;
    _searchPreferences.bodyFieldsOnly = false;

    //Set Search Preferences

    try
    {
        SearchResult result = _serviceInstance.search(objTransSearch);

        List<JournalEntry> lstJEntry = new List<JournalEntry>();
        List<JournalEntryLine> lstLineItems = new List<JournalEntryLine>();

        if (result.status.isSuccess)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= result.recordList.Length - 1; i += 1)
            {

                JournalEntry JEntry = (JournalEntry)result.recordList[i];
                lstJEntry.Add((JournalEntry)result.recordList[i]);

                if (JEntry.lineList != null)
                {

                    foreach (JournalEntryLine line in JEntry.lineList.line)
                    {
                        lstLineItems.Add(line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        try
        {
            _serviceInstance.logout();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```